# Loading json file into titan graph database

Tags: json, titan

I have given a task to load a json file into titandb with dynamodb as back end.Is there any java tutorial or if possible please upload java sample coding... 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titan is an abstraction layer so whether you use Cassandra, dynamo, hbase, etc, you merely need to find Titan data loading instructions.  They are a bit dated but you might want to start with these blog posts:

- http://thinkaurelius.com/2014/05/29/powers-of-ten-part-i/
- http://thinkaurelius.com/2014/06/02/powers-of-ten-part-ii/

The code examples work with an older version of Titan (the schema portion) but the concepts still apply.

You will find that the strategy for data loading with Titan has a lot to do with the size of your graph.  You said you are loading "a JSON file" so I imagine you have a smaller graph in the millions of edges.  In this case, a simple groovy script will likely suffice.  Write a script to [parse your JSON](http://www.groovy-lang.org/json.html) and write the data to the Titan.